# Cache blocks inserted via wysiwyg

Tags: magento-1.8, blocks, cache, block-cache

I have block definition in cms page

```
{{block type="divante_cdp/homeblog"}}
```

And construct method of my block

```
public function __construct(array $args = array())
{
    $this->setTemplate('page/html/homeblog.phtml');
    $this->addData(array(
            'cache_lifetime' => 3600,
            'cache_tags'     => array(Mage_Cms_Model_Block::CACHE_TAG,'tag_home_homeblog'),
        ));

    parent::__construct($args);
}
```

Block isn't cached. After run below command there is no tag `tag_home_homeblog`

```
n98-magerun.phar cache:report -t
```

What i'm doing wrong? Cache is enabled :)

Comment: put parent construct above in your constructor instead of put it as last one and then try again

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you need to put your `__construct()` like this.

```
public function __construct(array $args = array())
{
    parent::__construct($args);

    $this->setTemplate('page/html/homeblog.phtml');
    $this->addData(array(
            'cache_lifetime' => 3600,
            'cache_tags'     => array(Mage_Cms_Model_Block::CACHE_TAG,'tag_home_homeblog'),
        ));

}
```

Now parent `__construct()` will not alter the changes that your made in your custom block's `__construct()` . Thus it makes your `__construct()` alterations in effect.